# How can I get the controller and method name from a passed method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to make a function that can take a method as a parameter and get the name of the method and controller. Something like

```cs
public static string FormatName(Action controllerMethod)
{
    return $"{controllerMethod.MethodName}_{controllerMethod.ControllerName}"
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Method stuff
    }
}

public void PrintFormattedName()
{
    Console.Write(FormatName(MyMethod))  // "MyMethod_MyClass"
}
```

I believe passing an Action is the way to go, but how do I make it accept any Action regardless of the return type of the method? I'm not interested in anything but the name of the passed method and its controller, is there another way I can pass these without just having to pass the strings themselves? These are API endpoints if it makes a difference

Comment: You can try the [Url.Action()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-string)) helper

Comment: You can do that using `middleware`  without writing any extra method. `ActionFilter` middleware allow you to get your `controller`, `action` even the parameter name once the request executed.